# Invalid route name, already in use: 'root'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I get:

Invalid route name, already in use: 'root'
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created

routes.rb

```
AlectricaSite::Application.routes.draw do

  constraints lambda{ |req| ( req.subdomain == 'shop' || req.subdomain == 'servicios' ) } do
    root to: 'comercio/servicios#index'
  end
  constraints lambda{ |req|  req.subdomain == 'www' } do
    root to: 'electrico/album#hola'
  end
end
```

when trying to set a root_path for each subdomain (www, shop, servicios).

This solution works for rails 5, but rails 6.1 is complaining about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it could be you're encountering a conflict in your routes because you're using the same name root for two different routes.

Perhaps you can try:

```
AlectricaSite::Application.routes.draw do
  constraints lambda { |req| req.subdomain == 'shop' || req.subdomain == 'servicios' } do
    get '/', to: 'comercio/servicios#index', as: 'comercio_root'
  end

  constraints lambda { |req| req.subdomain == 'www' } do
    get '/', to: 'electrico/album#hola', as: 'electrico_root'
  end
end
```

The helper methods for those routes should be `comercio_root_path` and `electrico_root_path`

Answer (score 0):

A found a solution by doing this:

```
AlectricaSite::Application.routes.draw do

  get '/', to: 'comercio/servicios#index', constraints: { subdomain: 'shop' }
  get '/', to: 'comercio/servicios#index', constraints: { subdomain: 'servicios' }

  root to: 'electrico/album#hola'
....
end
```